# MAUI граф конструктор для XAML

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

вопрос не по коду. Есть ли какой-нибудь вариант, граф дизайнера(конструктора) для отображения дизайна приложения на MAUI? Просто комп слабый запускать андроид эмулятор. Может есть какой-нибудь онлайн конструктор, что бы потом XAML который написал там, перенести в VS

Comment: Можете отлаживать прямо на устройстве без эмулятора

Comment: Если речь про [Live Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-live-preview?view=vs-2022), то он в студии есть из коробки, с недавних пор вроде и MAUI поддерживает. Но писать UI с его использованием, это себя не уважать, молчу вообще про "онлайн конструкторы"... Вы как разработчик обязаны знать XAML и писать его ориентируясь на живом примере (как выше сказали, хоть на живом устройстве), это самый лучший и удобный вариант.